# How do I unset a shipping rate?

Tags: shipping-methods

I want to extend `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping` so that I can iterate through the collected methods and unset all but the lowest price. I do not want to do this on the frontend (which would probably be easier).

I have tried to debug '$this' in collectRates() but I just do not know how to unset a rate. If anyone can help me with this - even a workaround - that would be helpful.

The collectRates is in `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve all methods for supplied shipping data
 *
 * @todo make it ordered
 * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping_Method_Request $data
 * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
 */
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    $storeId = $request->getStoreId();
    if (!$request->getOrig()) {
        $request
            ->setCountryId(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_COUNTRY_ID, $request->getStore()))
            ->setRegionId(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_REGION_ID, $request->getStore()))
            ->setCity(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_CITY, $request->getStore()))
            ->setPostcode(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_ZIP, $request->getStore()));
    }

    $limitCarrier = $request->getLimitCarrier();
    if (!$limitCarrier) {
        $carriers = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $storeId);

        foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {
            $this->collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
        }
    } else {
        if (!is_array($limitCarrier)) {
            $limitCarrier = array($limitCarrier);
        }
        foreach ($limitCarrier as $carrierCode) {
            $carrierConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/' . $carrierCode, $storeId);
            if (!$carrierConfig) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to filter shipping method in onepage checkout?](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-filter-shipping-method-in-onepage-checkout/)

```
<global>
    ...
    <models>
        <shipping>
            <rewrite>
                <shipping>MagePsycho_Shipmentfilter_Model_Shipping</shipping>
            </rewrite>
        </shipping>
    </models>
    ...
</global>
```

Then in your observer

```
<?php
class MagePsycho_Shipmentfilter_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
{
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request)) {
            return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    protected function _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request = null)
    {
        //To Do : get list of all the carrier and find the code for the lowest
        if($carrierCode == 'flatrate'){ #Hide Flat Rate for non logged in customers
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that answer however I do not know in advance what my cheapest rate is, therefore I cannot just return false on them as they are collected. I am also hoping to learn a little bit of object oriented php, using methods, extending as required. There is a 'reset' method for instance and getCheapestRate but I don't know if that is what I need to investigate as I can return different methods per carrier, e.g. express and standard.